# Can you override a method of a superclass and…

Tags: java

#### Change the access modifier

- from public to private
- from private to public

#### Change the throw clause

- more exceptions
- less exceptions

#### Change the return type

- to a subtype
- to a super type

Please, can someone explain?

Comment: You can test all your questions.

Comment: Give it a shot, then you can answer your own question.

Comment: I know, but I expected someone to answer with an actual explanation to :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule of thumb for changing signatures in overrides is if a valid call to the parent is not a valid call to the child, you are no allowed to do it.

Of the scenarios you described:

- from public to private **NO** You are removing the method entirely from the public API, which would definitely break the caller
- from private to public **YES** Since you are now allowing more callers to call the method (but not disallowing any previous callers). This is true for any increases in visibility (`private` to default to `protected` to `public`).
- more exceptions **NO** No since the caller would need to catch more exceptions
- less exceptions **YES** Since the caller is allowed to catch exceptions that will never be thrown
- to a subtype **YES** Yes, since every instance of a subtype is also an instance of the supertype. The return value that the caller gets back will be an instance of the expected type.
- to a super type **NO** No, since the caller will be expecting an instance of one subtype and you could return an instance of a different subtype.

Other things you can do include:

- Change the type of an argument to a supertype, since any instance of the subtype that the caller would be passing in is also a valid value of the supertype.
- Change a throws declaration to a subtype of the exception since the callers catch logic for the supertype exception will also handle the subtype exception.

Comment: Wow, so I was wrong (well, if you're right) Thanks for answering my question with extra information! This is the answer I was hoping to get :)

Comment: "from private to public" This isn't overriding, since the subclass can't even see the method.

Comment: @cypressious Technically right, but that is what he asked. Editing to explain that it is increasing visibility.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some rules of Overriding:

- **Change the access modifier**

  You can't decrease the visibility

  because it can spoil whole thing at run-time when you can't access overloaded method of sub-class due to visibility down.

  Suppose the method is public in super-class and you have changed it to private while overriding in sub-class but since you have a reference of super-class so compiler will not complain but at run-time it will break down.
- **Change the throw clause**

  You can't throw newer checked or broader exception

  The same thing applies here as well since compiler looks for super-class method for throws but if at run-time the sub-class throws new or broader exception then who is responsible for handling all new checked exception that should be caught at compile time.
- **Change the return type**

  Only [Covariant return type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) are supported

  *Note:* covariant return type, means that the return type is allowed to vary in the same direction as the subclass.

Comment: So my answers would be: no - no - yes - yes - yes - no ?

Comment: This is correct.  But you also can't change the access modifier from private to public (which is increasing the visibility) because you can't override a private method.

Comment: that's what I am saying. You cant decrease the visibility.

Comment: changing `private` to `public` is increasing the visibility tho, right?

Answer (score 4):

This is a neat little article (http://crunchify.com/java-method-overriding-examples-and-concepts-overriding-rules/) that talks about overriding methods and some of the rules for it. Its very helpful and you should look at it. Some of the rules are below:

> • In java, a method can only be written in Subclass, not in same class.
>
> • The argument list should be exactly the same as that of the
>   overridden method.
>
> • The return type should be the same or a subtype of
>   the return type declared in the original overridden method in the
>   super class.
>
> • The access level cannot be more restrictive than the
>   overridden method’s access level. For example: if the super class
>   method is declared public then the overridding method in the sub class
>   cannot be either private or protected.
>
> • Instance methods can be
>   overridden only if they are inherited by the subclass.
>
> • A method
>   declared final cannot be overridden.
>
> • A method declared static cannot
>   be overridden but can be re-declared.
>
> • If a method cannot be inherited
>   then it cannot be overridden.
>
> • A subclass within the same package as
>   the instance’s superclass can override any superclass method that is
>   not declared private or final.
>
> • A subclass in a different package can
>   only override the non-final methods declared public or protected.
>
> • An
>   overriding method can throw any uncheck exceptions, regardless of
>   whether the overridden method throws exceptions or not. However the
>   overriding method should not throw checked exceptions that are new or
>   broader than the ones declared by the overridden method. The
>   overriding method can throw narrower or fewer exceptions than the
>   overridden method.
>
> • Constructors cannot be overridden.

Also here it he official Oracle article on overriding methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of these changes are related to what's called the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwhCYaYDn8EgNzAzZjA5ZmItNjU3NS00MzQ5LTkwYjMtMDJhNDU5ZTM0MTlh/edit?hl=en)(one of the [S.O.L.I.D  principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod)). This principle basically states that when you are interacting with an instance of a type, your super-class/interface in this case, all of the child types/implementors must expose at least that interface, and ideally, must also behave in generally the same manner.

Comment: These questions actually came from a powerpoint on that subject. Just wanted to make sure I got the right answers :)

Comment: It is a strange, small, circular world we live in then... :)

Answer (score 2):

- The subclass can only override instance methods which are inherited by it. Since private and final     methods are not inherited, they cannot be overridden.
- The return type of an overriding method should be same as, or a subclass of, the return type declared in the overridden superclass method.
- The argument list of overriding method should be same as that of overridden superclass method. This is important as different argument list results in overloading rather than overriding.
- The access modifier of overriding method should be same or less restrictive than that of superclass method. It cannot be more restrictive.
- The overriding method cannot throw exceptions that are new or broader than those declared by overridden superclass method. However, it can throw narrower or fewer exception than superclass method.
- Static methods cannot be overridden.